# Finding missing number between tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm working on the following 2 tables on Oracle 10g. I'm attempting a rather simple task, but can't get my query right, perhaps due to my lack of understanding of the basics. I want to query out the account_no from TEMP which is not present in BMF.

Two Tables:
Table 1: BMF:  1372 rows

```
account_no  |  trans_amount   | tracking_id

8149817     |   8100          |     72422912

8197743     |   9100          |     72422913

7165129     |   8100          |     72422914

8625861     |   8100          |     72422915

8463378     |   2100          |     72422916

8213330     |   3100          |     72422917
```

Table 2: temp : 1373 rows -- There is only ONE account_no in TEMP that's missing from BMF

```
account_no

8149817

8197743

7165129

8625861

8463378

8213330

84633

48
```

Expected result: 
8463348  -- As this number is not present in the BMF table.

My Query:

```
 select a1.account_no from TEMP a1, bmf a2 
 where a2.tracking_id between 72422912 and 72424283
 and a1.account_no != a2.account_no
```

Any pointers, with a correct query will be helpful

Regards,
novice

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT account_no FROM temp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT account_no FROM bmf 
                  WHERE bmf.account_no = temp.account_no)
```

This will have same execution plan as SQL in other answers here, but it states intention more clearly (at least to me).

Answer (score 3):

You want all column values, which are in one set of data (temp) but not in another (bmf)? That is what the ["Minus" operator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators005.htm#sthref893) does.

```
select account_no from TEMP
minus
select account_no from bmf
```

EDIT:
added doc link

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT account_no 
FROM TEMP
WHERE acount_no NOT IN (SELECT account_no FROM BMF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 select a1.account_no from TEMP a1 left join bmf a2 
 where a2.tracking_id between 72422912 and 72424283
 and a2.account_no = NULL
```

use a left join and then only take the entries that don't have a corresponding entry

Answer (score 1):

Your join syntax is [discouraged](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#insertedID6) by Oracle for outer joins.

You can do a left outer join and exclude the unjoined columns; this should be the most efficient approach. Something like this:

```
SELECT a1.account_no FROM TEMP a1
 LEFT JOIN bmf a2 ON a1.account_no = a2.account_no
 WHERE (a2.tracking_id between 72422912 and 72424283)
 AND a2.account_no IS NULL
```

Comment: can you add a reference to the 'discouraged by Oracle' comment?

Comment: I'd rather have a NOT EXIST or NOT IN query (the OP explicitely asks for rows "from TEMP which is not present in BMF"). The synthax with OUTER JOIN + NULL is awkward

Comment: @Vincent: the habit of using NOT IN with an additional query can quickly lead to a nested inner query, which is a complete performance killer. Since we're talking SQL, we're supposed to deal with sets, and not with procedural loop-like constructs...

Comment: @Lucero: actually NOT IN will generate the very same ANTI-JOIN plan as the OUTER JOIN + NULL. There is no inner query either in Svetlozar's solution nor in zendar's (try it).

Comment: @Vincent: I know that. This is why I wrote "can quickly lead to a nested inner query" - when one uses columns from the outer query in a more complex way.